# ActionBarSherlock Tabs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have to implement Tabs in my application using ActionBarSherlock. I am following this example [here](http://comfreek.blogspot.com/2012/06/actionbars-and-tabs-under-android-2x.html). Now i want to add buttons to one of the fragment, and perform an action on it. How do i do it ? Suppose this is the layout where the button is

```
public class AFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello, container, false);
    }
}
```

How do i read a button from the view ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class AFragment extends SherlockFragment {
private Button button;    
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflating the layout view  to this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello, container, false);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
   }
    @Override onClick() {
       switch(v.getId()_ {
          case R.id.button_id:
                       //Your logic for button goes here
                       break;
       }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is how it is done. as far as i can tell. I have not exactly gotten mine to work yet but in dont think my problem is here.

```
    private Button button;    

    public class AFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View inflater = inflate(R.layout.hello, container, false);
        button = (Button) inflater.findViewById(R.id.reminder_slider);
        button setOnItemClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //do stuff on item click aka @Override onClick()
        }
        return inflater;
    }
}
```

Comment: ADR has it. I forgot that you already have inflater defined in your arguments. Just change inflater to view

Answer (score 1):

```
private Button button;    

    public class AFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello, container, false);
        //finding the button by ID inside the inflated view
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnid);
        //setting an event
        button.setOnItemClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        });
        return view;
    }
```